# Fine-grained types with deduction and `keyof` in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

So I have a type

```
type A = {
  a?: T1,
  b?: T1
}
```

and I have a function

```
const fn: <N extends keyof A>(name: N) => ({ [P in N]: T2 })
    = name => ({ [name]: T2 });
```

The idea with that heavy generic expression is to statically infer the type of result. It works, I write `fn('a')` and compiler infers its type as `<"a">(name: "a") => { a: T2; }` except for the function itself it says `Type '{ [x: string]: T2; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in N]: T2 }'.`

Question: is there a way to write types for the function `fn`, keeping nice static type inference from literal, but making nasty type error go away?

Just overriding type with `as` is OK, but my attempts did not succeed.

Comment: Can you explain a bit, what are `T1` and `T2`? Are they generic types, or some arbitrary types not related to the topic? And what does `(v: number) => number[]` definition mean here?

Comment: Sorry, it was uncleaned `T2`

Comment: `T1` and `T2` are arbitrary bound (non-generic) parameters.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1715SBPeZSfLPPLkCtLys8_6NngAUY2UyaJVAahkbF6U/mobilepresent?slide=id.g414f239472_1_52 slide 17 seems like a good working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax works for me:

```
const fn = <N extends keyof A>(name: N) =>
    ({ [name]: T2 }) as ({ [P in N]: T2 });
```

Note that the reason you're getting that type error in the first place is that this is unsound if `N` is set to a non-singleton type.  A way to constrain `N` to be a singleton type, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17713), would help.

Comment: You could fix the soundness issue by having the return type be `{[K in N]: Record<K, T2>}[N]`, but the compiler still won't believe you that it's safe so an assertion is probably the best (or only) solution.

Comment: It says `cannot find name 'N'` for `N` in the type description.

Minor thing: I updated my question, `(v: number) => number[]` is `T2` for shortness

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.  Can you reproduce it on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and post a link?

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20T1%20%3D%20number%3B%0D%0Atype%20T2%20%3D%20string%3B%0D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3F%3A%20T1%2C%0D%0A%20%20b%3F%3A%20T1%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fn%20%3D%20%3CN%20extends%20keyof%20A%3E(name%3A%20N)%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(%7B%20%5Bname%5D%3A%20T2%20%7D)%20as%20(%7B%20%5BP%20in%20N%5D%3A%20T2%20%7D)%3B

Comment: OK, it works if I replace the first `T2` . with any value of that type.